# JQuery show/hide/toggle functions are not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

This is my view page in CI

```
<body>
<!-- Image and text -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Admin LTE</a>
    </div>
<!--     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
</ul> -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="sidenav">

  <a href="#" class="admin">Admin</a>
  <a href="#" class="teacher">Teacher</a>

  <a href="#" class="student">Student</a>
  <a href="#" class="batch">Batch</a>


</div>

<div class="main">

  <div id="admin" style="display: none;"><?php $this->load->view('V_Admin/Admin') ?></div>
  <div id="teacher" style="display: none;"><?php $this->load->view('V_Teacher/Teacher') ?></div>
  <div id="student" style="display: none;"><?php $this->load->view('V_Student/Student') ?></div>
  <div id="batch" style="display: none;"><?php $this->load->view('V_Batch/Batch') ?></div> 


<div>

</div>

</body>
```

This is JS script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.admin').click(function(){
      $('#admin').show();
      $('#teacher').hide();
      $('#student').hide();
      $('#batch').hide();
    });

    $('.teacher').click(function(){
      alert("teacher");
      $('#admin').hide();
      $('#teacher').show();
      $('#student').hide();
      $('#batch').hide();
    });

    $('.student').click(function(){
      $('#admin').hide();
      $('#teacher').hide();
      $('#student').show();
      $('#batch').hide();
    });

    $('.batch').click(function(){
      alert('batch');
      $('#admin').hide();
      $('#teacher').hide();
      $('#student').hide();
      $('#batch').show();
    });
  });
```

Problem is when I'm clicking Admin and Student it works fine, but not for Teacher and Batch. What's wrong here? But when I'm clicking Teacher and Batch alert for Teacher and Batch is showing, means the function is working but the show and hide for the div is not working

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.admin').click(function() {
    $('#admin').show();
    $('#teacher').hide();
    $('#student').hide();
    $('#batch').hide();
  });

  $('.teacher').click(function() {
    //alert("teacher");
    $('#admin').hide();
    $('#teacher').show();
    $('#student').hide();
    $('#batch').hide();
  });

  $('.student').click(function() {
    $('#admin').hide();
    $('#teacher').hide();
    $('#student').show();
    $('#batch').hide();
  });

  $('.batch').click(function() {
    //alert('batch');
    $('#admin').hide();
    $('#teacher').hide();
    $('#student').hide();
    $('#batch').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#" class="admin">Admin</a>
  <a href="#" class="teacher">Teacher</a>
  <a href="#" class="student">Student</a>
  <a href="#" class="batch">Batch</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div id="admin" style="display: none;">
    admin
  </div>
  <div id="teacher" style="display: none;">
    teacher
  </div>
  <div id="student" style="display: none;">
    student
  </div>
  <div id="batch" style="display: none;">
    batch
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine as seen in the demo.

Comment: But it's not working for me. :(

Comment: I am sorry but we can't solve an issue if can not be reproduced. As you can see the same code here is working fine here.

Comment: Yeah! actually out of 4 div 2 of them working fine, rest 2 is not. And the code for all is same. Don't know what's happening

Comment: also might worth checking first if they are open or not. if some of them do work and others don't might be because they where prev open and the state remains like that unntil you close them and reopen them based on what you click